# Eclipse CUDA PROFILER PLUGIN development

Tags: eclipse, plugins, cuda, profiler

I am little bit new in field of eclipse and I am trying to write a plugin for eclipse
which can provide a main menu with one sub menu NVIDIA VISUAL PROFILER.After clicking 
on which it should profile my application. Can anybody suggest some good tutorial or 
any such type of PLUGIN which can give me some idea.

Comment: Why don't you use [NVIDIA® Nsight™ Eclipse Edition](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-eclipse-edition)? What you are describing already exists and is provided by the CUDA SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BenC mentioned, Nsight Eclipse Edition has complete Visual Profiler integrated as a part of the whole IDE experience.

NVIDIA tools team does not provide Visual Profiler as a standalone component that can be integrated in Eclipse products. All that can be done with current Visual Profiler is calling it from the command line (e.g. by using [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)). You do not even need to create a plugin for this as you may leverage existing "External Tools" facilities.

Please let us know more about specific requirements you have for integrating Visual Profiler in your Eclipse workbench.